# Why does difference in two chrono time points result in seconds?

Tags: c++, time, duration, c++-chrono

I have the following code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main()
{
    
    using my_timepoint = time_point<high_resolution_clock, nanoseconds>;
    
    my_timepoint now = system_clock::now();
    my_timepoint then = system_clock::now() - seconds{1};
  
    duration<double> my_dur = now - then;
   
    cout << my_dur.count();
}
```

Here `my_timepoint` is expressed in `nanoseconds` still I get output of this code as `1`. Why is it not `1e+09`? How does the difference in two time points evaluated?

Comment: I recommend a chrono video tutorial:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M  Cost:  1h.  It will answer this and several other basic questions about chrono, bringing the viewer up to speed by the end of the hour.

Answer (score 0):

The duration template takes a ratio argument as described here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration

The code posted is using the default value (1 tick every 1 second), so naturally when you ask it for `count()`, it will return just 1, to represent the number of ticks that have elapsed.

You can construct a duration object that uses a different ratio, then you'll get `1e+09`:

```
duration<double, std::ratio<1, 1000000000>> my_dur = now - then;
```